# Repeating a dataframe value N times based on another column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have exported a csv file, imported it into IPython, and then selected two columns that I want to analyze.

I want to create a histogram from this data:

- "average time taken (line items)" is the x-axis of the histogram.
- "number of line items" is the frequency for each "average time".

**Question**: How am I able to achieve this? I would like to create an array to store each instance of "average time taken (line items)" N times, where N is "number of line items".

However, I do not know how to code this. I tried using a list comprehension but couldn't get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('eidpc1_prechange.csv', skiprows=11)
filterdf = pd.DataFrame(df[['Average time taken (line items)',
                            'Number of line items.1']]).dropna()
histogram = [filterdf['Average time taken (line items)'] 
             for line in filterdf['Number of line items.1']]
```

[picture of Ipython code and results](http://puu.sh/hSCFA/55c70fbedd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy` has a [computational-oriented version of histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

`matplotlib` has a [plot-oriented version of histogram](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html).

In particular, note the `weights` argument, which can be used, well, to weight the samples. E.g.,

```
pyplot.hist(
    df['Average time taken(line items)'].values, 
    weights=df['Number of line items.1'].values);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this? I'm already using `matplotlib` but my data is pre-counted. I want to expand this 'pre-count' by duplicating each value by its frequency.

Comment: Have you seen the ``weights`` arg in these functions? I think it's what you want, no? If not, perhaps you could edit your question to explain why not.

Comment: I tried this  `filterdf.hist(['Average time taken(line items)'], weights = ['Number of line items.1'])` the error it returned was "average time taken (line items) not in index"

Comment: Note my answer explicitly used the lower-level libraries. Tried to clarify further, though.